# define variables while using curl to POST to url

Tags: shell, curl

what is the correct syntax to define  :
$data as :

```
   {\"username\":\"[$username]\",\"password\":\"[$password]\",\"webdata\": [$syntax]}" \
```

and replace it the  my shell script

```
      result=$(curl -D - -k -m 10  -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
            -d "{\"username\":\"[$username]\",\"password\":\"[$password]\",\"webdata\":   [$syntax]}" \
     https://${host}/api 2>/dev/null |head -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume bash (>=3.0); that you have previously set $username, $password and $syntax.
A simple option is:

```
 printf -v data '{"username":"[%s]","password":"[%s]","webdata":[%s]}"' \
   "$username" "$password" "$webdata"
```

(curl's "-d" is implicitly ASCII, you will have trouble if you use any multi-byte UTF-8 characters.
It may be more robust to use --data-binary, and/or write your request to a file instead and load
it with "--data-binary @request.tmp".)